# How to solve connection problem between mlflow and bucket s3 of aws?

Tags: amazon-s3, mlflow

I am trying to save the results of an ML model in an S3 bucket so that I can view them in MLFLOW.
I use the following code which code is located in train.py:

```
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://127.0.0.1:5000")
mlflow.set_experiment("wine")

with mlflow.start_run():

        lr = ElasticNet(alpha=0.2, l1_ratio=l1_ratio, random_state=42)
        lr.fit(train_x, train_y)

        predicted_qualities = lr.predict(test_x)

        (rmse, mae, r2) = eval_metrics(test_y, predicted_qualities)

        mlflow.log_param("alpha", alpha)
        mlflow.log_param("l1_ratio", l1_ratio)
        mlflow.log_metric("rmse", rmse)
        mlflow.log_metric("r2", r2)
        mlflow.log_metric("mae", mae)

        tracking_url_type_store = urlparse(mlflow.get_tracking_uri()).scheme

        # Model registry does not work with file store
        if tracking_url_type_store != "file":
            # Register the model
            # There are other ways to use the Model Registry, which depends on the use case,
            # please refer to the doc for more information:
            # https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/model-registry.html#api-workflow
            mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr, "model", registered_model_name="ElasticnetWineModel")
        else:
            mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr, "model")
```

I have been able to successfully run scenario 1, 2 and 3 from the MLFlow documentation https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html. For this last scenario I created a Minio https://min.io/ to create a local s3 repository and it worked correctly.

**The problem** is that in scenario 4, when uploading the generated files to an s3 bucket from my amazon account, it creates a default intermediate folder inside the bucket itself with the same name as the bucket as follows:
Amazon S3 > Buckets > es-mlflow > es-mlflow/ > 1/ > 5924d939c0030f2/ > artifacts/ > model/

To raise the service I use the command of scenario 4:
mlflow server --backend-store-uri sqlite:///mydb.sqlite --default-artifact-root s3://es-mlflow with which I save the metrics and parameters in local and artifacts in s3.

But when I raise on port 5000 by default the mlflow service to display the saved model it does not load what is saved in s3, i.e. artifacts.

The following warning is obtained

````
2023/04/24 11:25:08 ERROR mlflow.server: Exception on /ajax-api/2.0/mlflow/artifacts/list [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fllaneza/miniconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/fllaneza/miniconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/fllaneza/miniconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/fllaneza/miniconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/Users/fllaneza/miniconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/server/handlers.py", line 475, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/fllaneza/miniconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/server/handlers.py", line 516, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/fllaneza/miniconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/server/handlers.py", line 922, in _list_artifacts
    artifact_entities = _get_artifact_repo(run).list_artifacts(path)
  File "/Users/fllaneza/miniconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/s3_artifact_repo.py", line 188, in list_artifacts
    for result in results:
  File "/Users/fllaneza/miniconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 264, in __iter__
    response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
  File "/Users/fllaneza/miniconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 352, in _make_request
    return self._method(**current_kwargs)
  File "/Users/fllaneza/miniconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 508, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/fllaneza/miniconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 911, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The specified key does not exist.```

I think what is happening is that MLFlow is looking at this path: 
Amazon S3 > Buckets > es-mlflow > 1/ > 5924d939c0030f2/ > artifacts/ > model/

instead of this one which is where it currently sits every time I re-train my model.
Amazon S3 > Buckets > es-mlflow > es-mlflow/ > 1/ > 5924d939c0030f2/ > artifacts/ > model/

Is there any way to solve the problem?
````